# Ionic - Live deploy does not work on Android <5.0

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, deployment

I have an issue with the ionic cordova ionic plugin. I am doing live deploy for my app and it works on android 5.0 or higher, but fails on android 4.x, and I don´t know why.

I have all correctly, same app id on app.module and config.xml, same id ionic project on my ionic dashboard and app.module…

I don´t know if this plugin does not work on low android versions because on higher versiones is working fine.

Regards,

Comment: which plugin your mentioning?

Comment: cordova-plugin-ionic

https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/setup/#installing-ionic-pro-plugin

Comment: any error content?

Comment: Nop, the app just launch without any errors but nothing update.